# How to properly use generalized method of moments (GMM) estimation with plm in R?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, generalized-moments, plm

In the context of panel data analysis my key independent variable `wage` affects the response not immediately but rather over time. Therefore I would like to use some lagged values of `wage` $X_{it-1}$, $X_{it-2}$, $X_{it-3}$ ... I read that in order to avoid multicollinearity by using some Finite Distributed Lags one can try to use the Infinite Distributed Lag model.

I would like to estimate the infinite
distributed lag model with a GMM and the time fixed effects R library `plm`:

$$Y_{t} =\alpha+\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \beta X_{t-s}+e_t$$

I [read](http://www.lse.ac.uk/geographyAndEnvironment/whosWho/profiles/neumayer/pdf/Article%20in%20Journal%20of%20Conflict%20Resolution%20(Tourism).pdf)  that this equation can be transformed for the panel data context as follows: 
$$Y_{it} =\lambda+Y_{it-1}+\beta X_{it}+ \gamma Z_{t} + e_{it}$$

Im trying to implement that model with some covariates using `plm`.

**Question:** Is that model correct? Is the following implementation of that model correct?

```
\ Some R code


data("EmplUK", package = "plm")
library(plm)
pdata <- pdata.frame(EmplUK, index=c("year", "firm"))

# Here I lag the key independent variable as well:

plm.gmm<- pgmm(log(emp) ~  lag(log(emp),1)+lag(log(wage),2)+output+factor(year)| lag(log(emp), 2:99),
data = pdata,
transformation = "ld",
effect = "individual")

# Here I lag only the dependent variable(which seems to correspond to the transformed equation above:

plm.gmm<- pgmm(log(emp) ~   lag(log(emp),1)+wage+output+factor(year)| lag(log(emp), 2:99),
data = pdata,
transformation = "ld",
effect = "individual")
```